# ValidationError at [u'Enter a valid date/time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]] format.']

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

forms.py

```
class SearchFilterForm(Form):
    fromdate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yy','class':'datefield','readonly':'readonly'}))
todate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yy','class':'datefield','readonly':'readonly'}))
```

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    created_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Created')
    sent_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Sent')
```

In database the date objects is saved in this format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` and i am used in forms.py the format is `dd/mm/yyyy`.I am not getting any error if i use yyyy-mm-dd format in form.Since i used dd/mm/yyyy format in form i am getting this validation error.I want to know how to handle this.

Comment: I would *hope* the data isn't stored as text in the database at all. You should avoid string conversions as far as possible - fetching the data from the database *as* a date/time type if at all possible. I don't know Django well enough to help with that, but that should be your goal.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fortunately enough, Django does indeed use a date field to store dates in the DB - but I asume that whatever tool Monk happens to be using outputs the dates in this text format : )

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: That's my expectation too. I think it's vitally important to understand the difference between the inherent nature of your data, and its textual representation in some tool or other.

Comment: @JonSkeet And I couldn't agree more!

Answer (score 5):

You should use a `DateField` in your form and configure `input_formats` to support the format you'd like to use:

```
ACCEPTABLE_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y',       # '25-10-2006'
                      '%d/%m/%Y',       # '25/10/2006'
                      '%d/%m/%y']       # '25/10/06'
                      # Add your own at will, but be mindful of collisions.


class SearchFilterForm(Form):    
    fromdate = forms.DateField(input_formats=ACCEPTABLE_FORMATS)
    todate = forms.DateField(input_formats=ACCEPTABLE_FORMATS)
```

[See the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datefield) for more!

---

Better yet, [you can enable localization in your Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/), and let django use the correct format for you automatically!

```
# settings.py
USE_L10N = True

# forms.py
class SearchFilterForm(Form):    
    fromdate = forms.DateField(localize=True)
    todate = forms.DateField(localize=True)
```

Comment: ,i tried my code in same approach,i am getting the same error.This is i am using in a search scenario,so after giving from and to date and hit search button reply this.